# I screwed up X or the window manager or something else. How to undo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in a VM on virtualbox.

Installed guest additions. Installed "proprietary 3d driver". Installed package build-essential. And a couple of others (nothing out of the ordinary-- I was trying out node.js so I did all the packages that building that requires. Also did freeglut3 and mesa-utils)

Then I decided I'm not happy with the window manager (which is not gnome, but Unity?). I have reached this conclusion after a few hours in practically every version of Ubuntu I have ever used.

run `sudo apt-get install xmonad`.

Log out.

Select xmonad when logging in. Screen's stuck.

Reset.

Blackness. X-cursor.

I was able to boot to recovery root shell from grub.

What's next? All I wanted to do was try `xmonad`... This has got to be the quickest I've ever irreversibly (hopefully not. this is where you come in) borked a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's stuck? Xmonad doesn't load up anything by default, so you'll just get the same background image as was shown in your login manager. See if alt shift enter doesn't open a terminal.

More default key bindings: (click to zoom)

[image]

Comment: Well. That's what I get for assuming it would be friendly enough to at least give me a hint. But why has it taken over the login screen? How do I get Unity/GNOME back?

Comment: Okay, Alt Shift Q gets me out. It was auto-logging me in, so that's how I got stuck in xmonad. Thanks for that link!